# Advanced Search - How to remove navigation

Tags: advanced-search

How do I get advanced search in sharepoint 2013 to display the results without the navigation.  I don't want anything to show but the advanced search results and the search box once I hit the search button on advanced search.  Editing the miscellaneous section of the advanced search page to append ?IsDlg=0 to result.aspx doesn't work.  Is there another setting somewhere else I need to go to accomplish this?